# Temporal workflow resetWorkflowExecution not working

Tags: typescript, temporal-workflow

Whenever I tried to reset a temporal workflow I got this error:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Workflow machines must exist, we just created/updated them: WorkflowMissingError { run_id: "2bd9d9c7-3f7d-42c5-93d7-4ab43595d988" }', sdk-core\src\workflow\workflow_tasks\mod.rs:304:14
```

reset workflow always shows in running state, even If I try to start a new workflow, the new workflow also shows in running state only. Temporal UI shows StartToCloseTimeout error for reset workflow and new workflow.

Here is my tctl command

```
tctl workflow reset -w 0235cb83-3b74-4220-b76b-483c1af8baca  --event_id 7  --reason 'reset
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the TypeScript SDK, versions <= `0.19.2`, that should be fixed in the next release.

Core issue fixed here: https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-core/pull/287

Brought into sdk-typescript main here: https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-typescript/pull/568